# using custom domain in caddy gives tls error

Tags: caddy

I have the following caddy file -

```
localhost {
    respond "Hello World !"
}

auth.demo.app.com {
    respond "Hello auth app"
}
```

When I do a `sudo caddy reload` I get the following error -

> 2021/01/23 08:05:07.347   ERROR   tls job failed  {"error":
> "auth.demo.app.com: obtaining certificate: context canceled"}

this is the error I see in the log -

> 2021/01/23 08:08:22.981   ERROR   tls.issuance.acme.acme_client   challenge
> failed    {"identifier": "auth.demo.app.com", "challenge_type":
> "tls-alpn-01", "status_code": 400, "problem_type":
> "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:tls", "error": "remote error: tls: no
> application protocol"} 2021/01/23
> 08:08:22.981  ERROR   tls.issuance.acme.acme_client   validating
> authorization {"identifier": "auth.demo.app.com", "error":
> "authorization failed: HTTP 400 urn:ietf:params:acme:error:tls -
> remote error: tls: no application protocol", "order":
> "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/17665783/227021191",
> "attempt": 1, "max_attempts": 3}

obtaining certificate: context canceled

Comment: That message looks like Caddy is trying to create a certificate via Letsencrypt, and the certificate creation fails for some reason.